# Command failed: /tmp/5184df82/bin/pip install -t /tmp/58dc369a -r /tmp/58dc369a/requirements.txt

Tags: python, flask, hosting, vercel

i am basically hosting my web app made of python flaslk html and css on vercel . it showing this error Command failed: /tmp/5184df82/bin/pip install -t /tmp/58dc369a -r /tmp/58dc369a/requirements.txt

solution of my error